# How do I return the final discounted price instead of the discounted amount off?

Tags: java, methods

I am creating a method that takes a percent as a parameter and decreases the price by that percent.

```
public void lowerPriceBy(double percent){
    price = price/100*percent;
}
```

How to I get my method to return the final discounted price of the car instead of the discounted amount?

For example if the car costs $10,000 and the percentage is 5% I want to return Price = $9500 but I'm only getting Price = $500 when I do the calculations.

Comment: for a start ... if you want your method to return something, it should `return something` ... as for your maths question it should return price with the discount subtracted from the price

Comment: @shree.pat18 guess again

Comment: @Bravo D'oh! Should be `price * (1 - discount)`

Comment: @shree.pat18 no ... since discount is not even defined!!! try again :p - `price * (1 - percent/100)`

Comment: We're splitting hairs at this point. Percent is not a particularly meaningful variable name to begin with

Answer (score 0):

You can get percent like this

Price= 10,000
Discount= 5%

Price after Discount= 10,000 - (10,000 * (5/100))

Answer will be= 9,500

Answer (score 0):

It's a good thing to see your effort, but here are the issues with the question.

1. Like they have noticed in the comments, your code is in `Java` and not `Javascript`
2. As @Anuj Kumar pointed out, the logic of getting the Discounted Price is `Price after Discount= 10,000 - (10,000 * (5/100))`

With this implementation I also suggest making the method name specify what argument it accepts by changing it to `lowerPriceByPercentage`

Here is a working code of what you want to acheive:

```
public class Main{

    static double price;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        price = 10000;
        lowerPriceByPercentage(5);
        System.out.println(price);
    }

    public static void lowerPriceByPercentage(double percent){
        price -= price*(percent/100);
    }
}
```

Run this online: https://onlinegdb.com/7V1Z33HbR

**If you want the method to `return` the value you should:**

1. Make the method return type as `double`
2. Use the `return` keyword

With `return`:

```
public class Main{

    static double price;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        price = 10000;
        price = lowerPriceByPercentage(5);
        System.out.println(price);
    }

    public static double lowerPriceByPercentage(double percent){
        return price - price*(percent/100);
    }
}
```

Run this online: https://onlinegdb.com/bqx3vcYkA